# While Debugging Project Showing FrameWork.dart Error

Tags: flutter, dart

```
    warning: Run script build phase 'Run Script' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
    warning: Run script build phase 'Thin Binary' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
    Result bundle written to path:
        /var/folders/_2/1190j1x91296nz36bsq1qw240000gn/T/flutter_tools.aesmFk/flutter_ios_build_temp_dirrKPou9/temporary_xcresult_bundle
```

Is There any one to help me

Comment: You also need to show what you did to get this error.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.